# How can I debug code running in a delayed_job task in the IRB console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I have a background task that runs using delayed_job.

I can see that it does run from the logging statements. It does not seem to have the correct result, compared to running it in the foreground, so I want to debug it in the IRB console.

I am running the background task with

```
rake jobs:work
```

and it does not trigger the debugger statement.

How can I load the debugger?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Start a standard rails console

```
ruby script/console
```

And start a worker inside here, this will see and trigger the debugger statement.

```
worker = Delayed::Worker.new
worker.start
```

Comment: Delayed::Worker.new.start

Comment: bundle exec rails runner "Delayed::Worker.new.start"

Comment: This is amazing. All this time I was in the dark on console output using a delayed job. Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

I use pry as my console and remote debugger. [Pry website here](https://pry.github.io/), [Pry rails gem here](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails). In your code, you add `binding.pry` statements to have your app stop executing and open the console. It works the same with `delayed_job` as it does with your rails app. Make sure you are running `delayed_job` in the foreground though, so it is still attached to the terminal. E.g., start `delayed_job` with:

```
rake jobs:work
```

Comment: Actually worth noting that if you've added the breakpoint (binding.pry instruction) *after* you've run the queue, then you must first stop & relaunched the queue with rake jobs:work so that the breakpoint is taken into account